# Failed to instantiate module angularUtils.directives.dirPagination 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination' is not available

Tags: angularjs

My pagination is working good but the problem is the script automatically getting deleted from index.html page, What may be causing it to delete?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the script tag associated to this pagination Utility into your `index.html` file by using a **cdn** kind of way

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>
```

**or** by specifying the local path of this plugin inside your project directory like

```
<script src="bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>
```

(where *bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination.js* being my path to this utility file inside my project directory)